# Configure Apache VirtualHosts behind a Load Balancer

Tags: apache, load-balancing, virtualhost

I have two servers, private IPs, Apache 2.4. I am serving the same content in both servers and there is a load balancer in front of these servers.

Load balancer uses a public IP, and there is a domain (mycompany.com) associated with it.

However, the client bought a new domain and want to use the same servers to serve the new content.

As far as I understand I need to configure VirtualHosts. I've read the documentation regarding VirtualHosts and it seems to be a case for name-based virtual hosts.

But since the public IP for the hostname is associated with the balancer, I do not know how I should configure the private servers in order that they be able to know how to solve which content to serve.

Appreciate the guidance.

Comment: Solved with http://serverfault.com/a/835998/195783

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved using this answer:

> Apache does not need to resolve anything regarding DNS.
>
> Just make sure each new virtualhost for the new domains have the appropiate "ServerName" entry reflecting that new domain, this way Apache HTTPD will know where to deliver the request with specified Host.

Link: https://serverfault.com/a/835998/195783